# error on getDrawable

Tags: android

```
private int ServiceLeft;
private int ServiceRight;
private int Services;

final TextView countTextViewPlusL = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewCountL);
final Button ServiceButtonLeft = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonServiceLeft);
final TextView countTextViewPlusR = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewCountR);
final Button ServiceButtonRight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonServiceRight);

View.OnClickListener listner = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
           case R.id.ButtonServiceRight:
                ServiceRight++;
                break;
           case R.id.ButtonServiceLeft:
                ServiceLeft++;
                break;
        }
        if(Services % 2 == 0) {
            getDrawable(R.drawable.test);
        }
    }
};
```

i get an error on "getDrawable"

```
getDrawable(R.drawable.test);
```

it says: The method getDrawable(int) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}.

how to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
MyActivity.this.getResources().getDrawable(R.id.test);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a scope problem.

Assume your class wherein all this code is located has the signature:

```
public class MyAct extends Activity
```

Then you must call

```
MyAct.this.getDrawable (R.drawable.test);
```

while inside the OnClickListener.

Comment: i did that but now i get: 

`The method getDrawable(int) is undefined for the type MyActivity`

Answer (score 0):

Call it throug YourActivityName.this.getDrawable(R.drawable.test);